# Spring mvc validation form with annotation not working after applying decorator tag for styling

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to get Validation errors on my jsp page using spring mvc form validation with annotation.Earlier it was working fine but after using decorator tag in jsp page for designing menu it is not showing in any validation errors.Although Binding Result contains all the errors but it is not showing validation errors on  the required page.